# Toggle accordion items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Js accordion, when i click an item, the panel opens, to close it you have to click on another item, i need to add the possibility of closing the active panel after clicking the **AccButton**

Here is my code :

```
const { active, setActive } = useContext(AccordionContext)

const eventHandler = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActive(index);
}

return (
    <AccItem id={props.index}>
        <AccButton
            onClick={(e) => eventHandler(e, props.index)}
            aria-expanded={ active === props.index ? 'true' : 'false' }
            aria-disabled={ active === props.index ? 'true' : 'false' }
        >
            <AccItemTitle>
                {props.description}
            </AccItemTitle>
        </AccButton>

        <AccPanel elWidth={props.elWidth}>
            <PanelToggle toggle={active === props.index}></PanelToggle>
        </AccPanel>

    </AccItem>
)
```

Comment: Are u expecting toggle kind of accordion?

Comment: If you use radio button input triggers you don't need any JS at all - just saying.

Comment: does setting it to null if there is an index value, work?

Comment: @Jagadeesh yeah exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a check if `active !== index` and otherwise set active to `null`. Like this:

```
const eventHandler = (e, index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActive(index !== active ? index : null);
}
```